# Intel page showing portals labelled "Zipcar"?

Tags: ingress

I see a bunch of portals near my area that are labelled "Zipcar location" and have no photo, but instead have the same logo in all of them. Any ideas what those might be?

Comment: @Retrosaur I wasn't aware of the partnerships.

Comment: @meme-scientist The whole point of arqade is to have information that is easily searchable. People googling for zipcar portal now hit this page. It would have been harder to find the answer if it wasn't for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Zipcar](http://www.zipcar.com/) is a car rental company, they probably signed a partnership with Google/Niantic to be part of the game, now every zipcar parking spot is a portal (that will lead many people around their locations).

Another partnership is made with [Jamba Juice](http://www.jambajuice.com/), their shops are also portals now.

Comment: The partnerships announced also include Hint water & Chrome apparel & messenger bags, no news on portals for them so far.

Comment: @Alok there are no portals for Hint water but there where ingress codes at the bottles.

Comment: ... ouch. :( That's a bit, um, disheartening to hear. I'm not playing to be someone's marketing campaign.

Comment: @IlariKajaste so you expect them to let you play out of the goodness of their hearts? "If you're not paying for a product, then by default you are the product"

Comment: @Doktor J I'd rather pay for it, thanks. But really, they're already getting tons of data from players.